# Domain reg - own server - need nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I have a domain registered for which I can only set the nameserver,
Now I have my own server.

I used to have hosting and nameserver through a hosting company, but that is about to expire. I don't want to use them anymore.

Could I setup dns on my own server and point my domain to that nameserver's ip address?
Or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my own DNS server to host my domain, running on a VPS.

I use [tinyDNS](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html), but any authoritative DNS server would work as well.

It is generally considered to be a really bad idea to have a single DNS server but all the data I serve from that DNS server is on that same server, so it doesn't bother me -- one thing fails it all fails.  Needless to say, this isn't 'best practices' for anything.

If you do this you may need to fake out registrar.  They typically want 2 different name servers so I've told it to use ns1.example.org and ns2.example.org that both happen to have the same IP address.  Also make sure the names you tell your registrar (which become [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_records#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)) the same information that you have in your server's DNS.

Also, you'll need to have a static IP address somewhere.

Again, it works but it isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: dnsmadeeasy.com's $29.95/yr for 10 domains, heck, zoneedit's free, but renting a VPS and running your own tinyDNS server is the answer?  Umm what?

Comment: I'm a control freak. I don't do anything important on that box. I did/do it to learn exactly how things work.  I would never suggest you do this for anything even slightly important, but it is valuable / useful to know how the whole stack works.  Oh -- and the VPS service I have is extremely inexpensive.

Comment: I'm not knocking you, I run an authoritative nameserver for a couple of I-don't-care domains that I run for websites for myself, friends, etc. when I ran out of free zoneedit zones, but it wouldn't be my first choice for anything remotely important.

Answer (score 3):

While you certainly could setup BIND and run your own authoritative nameserver for your domain, I wouldn't recommend it, when there's very inexpensive and more capable/resilient options out there like No-IP.com, easyDNS.com, zoneedit.com, and (haven't tried it yet) Amazon's Route 53 service.

Comment: Zoneedit gives 2 dns zones free, will that do?

Comment: Other domains I registered with another company come with my own panel to adjust the ip to my server, they were cheaper than the 1 dollar a month (not trying to be a cheapskate) but my .nl names were 14 euro for 5 years including nameserver.

Comment: Zoneedit will work -- you only need one zone per domain.